# WPF - Implementing System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged for Base Class

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I'd like to implent the System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged interface for a property on a base class, but I'm not quite sure how to hook it up.

Here's the signature for the property I'd like to get notifications for:

```
public abstract bool HasChanged();
```

And my code in the base class for handling the change:

```
public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

How do I handle the hookup of the event in the base class without having to call OnPropertyChanged() in each child class?

Thanks,
Sonny

EDIT:
OK... so I think that when the value for HasChanged() changes, I'm supposed to call `OnPropertyChanged("HasChanged")`, but I'm not sure how to get that into the base class.  Any ideas?

Comment: Generally speaking, this is not possible.

Comment: Also, `HasChanged` is a method here, not a property. Copy/paste error?

Comment: not true, he can still update the base class's property, see my edited answer below.

Comment: @Sonny Boy: The `HasChanged()` is an abstract method in your question, and you canNot do what you are after because an abstract method provides no actual implementation.

Comment: Is the base class in a different assembly?

Comment: So why not implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the base class?

Comment: Can you provide some code?  That's what I'm actually trying to accomplish but I'm unsure how to hook it all up to fire when HasChanged returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //make it protected, so it is accessible from Child classes
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

}
```

Notice the OnPropertyChanged accessible level is protected. And then in your concrete class or child classes, you do:

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.person.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.person.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: after reading the OP question again, I realize that he does not want to call the `OnPropertyChanged` in the child class, so I am pretty sure this will work:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool hasChanged = false;
    public bool HasChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hasChanged;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hasChanged = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HasChanged");
        }
    }

    //make it protected, so it is accessible from Child classes
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

and in child class:

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        base.HasChanged = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you really should check for equality of value and backing field before setting and raising the changed event if ( value != this.person.name)

Comment: @Muad'Dib: is this because the `this.person` can be null? or Is it because we don't want to raise the event if nothing is changed?

Comment: @VoodooChild because we don't want to raise the event.  I mean, if you raise it and nothing has changed, then you are,essentially, lying. also, if you are unnecessarily raising the changed event, you are waisting cycles and slowing things down.

Comment: @Muad'Dib: are we really slowing things down? I mean aren't we going through an extra step to check the equality now?

Comment: yes, that is 1 small step.  think about it, though--if you are binding to the property (the main reason for raising a changed event), now you are setting in motion a whole slew of actions by saying it has changed, including a (relatively) expensive render

Comment: @Muad'Dib: I think I agree with you there. Can you provide a source recommending this please? I have a project where we are using `INotifyPropertyChanged` quite a bit, alot actually and I know we are not doing the equality check anywhere when raising that event. I would like to pass this on to the system architect and see what he think about it...

Comment: sorry, don't have any links i can share with you. :(

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the recommendation :)