# Method to pass 3 different data types to do the same thing?

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures

I think the title might be wrong.. haha unsure.. anyway..

I have 3 different data types..

```
public class data1
{
    public Color color;
    public int len;
    public DrawingVisual dv;
    Other vars...
}
public class data2
{
    public Color color;
    public int len;
    public DrawingVisual dv;
    Other vars different from data1 vars...
}
```

Etc...

How can I create a function to pass these in and then get the vars I need inside the function..
Example..

```
void Something(var data)
{
    switch (typeof(data))
    {
         case data1:

         break;
         case data1:

         break;
    }
}
```

This wont work obviously.. but its just an example..

How can I actually do this?

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing to do with data in `Something` method? Are you going to use 'other vars'?

Comment: `void Something(var data)` is not a valid statement. Compiler should complain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider to create classes hierarchy, and move method *Something* to that hierarchy. Base class:

```
public abstract class Data
{
    public Color color;
    public int len;
    public DrawingVisual dv;

    public abstract void Something();
}
```

And two derived classes *Data1* and *Data2*:

```
public class Data1 : Data
{
    // Other vars...

    public override void Something()
    {
        // Use base class data and other vars
    }
}

public class Data2 : Data
{
    // Other vars different from Data1 vars

    public override void Something()
    {
        // different implementation
    }
}
```

Now when you have instances of these classes, you can simply call *Something* on each item without trying to determine its type. Each item will have all required variables to complete action:

```
List<Data> items = // get list of Data1 and Data2
foreach(Data data in items)
    data.DoSomething();
```

Comment: I think this is what I wanted.. I would of never been able to figure something like this out with out help.. Thanks..

Comment: If I have INotifyPropertyChanged on my data.. can I still do this? Seems it don't work right if I do..

Comment: @ChrisFazzio [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4289490/1991801) might give you insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object` instead of `var`

```
void Something(object data)
{
    if(typeof(data) == data1.GetType())
    {

    }
    else
    if(typeof(data) == data2.GetType())
    {

    } 
}
```

Your classes seem they have common attributes you can use inheritance. Make a base abstract class and inherit remaining from it.

```
public abstract class Data
{
    public Color color;
    public int len;
    public DrawingVisual dv;

    public abstract void Something();
}

public class Data1 : Data
{
      //Addition methods go here
}

public class Data2 : Data
{
      //Addition methods go here
}
```

As a additional note I assume you will use follow the naming conventions for properties and classes etc.

Comment: Thanks, I was overlooking this.. haha... Would you say this is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might want to reconsider using public fields and use public properties instead. Two options you might consider.

**Implement a shared interface**

Considering both your class have the same properties, you could have an interface:

```
public interface IData
{
    Color color {get;set;}
    int len {get;set;}
    DrawingVisual dv {get;set;}
}

public interface Data1
{
    public Color color {get;set;}
    public int len {get;set;}
    public DrawingVisual dv {get;set;}
}

public interface Data2
{
    public Color color {get;set;}
    public int len {get;set;}
    public DrawingVisual dv {get;set;}
}

void Something(IData data)
{
   // use the properties defined in the IData interface
}

Something(new Data1());
Something(new Data2());
```

**Use method overloading**

```
void Something(data1 data)
{
    // Do something specific using data1 class
}

void Something(data2 data)
{
    // Do something specific using data2 class
}

Something(new data1());
Something(new data2());
```

I'd suggest using the first option.

Comment: Why implement 3 identical contracts ? Just to distinguish types ? I would suggest to create abstract class and implement specialized method in each child class as @lazyberezovsky did.

Comment: @MechanicalObject It is _one_ option. I'm not saying it is _ideal_. If Chris can't refactor the class, it still is a valid option.

Comment: It's all good.. Every post here will help me to fix my classes to perform better..  Right now my stuff is like jelly slapped on bread.. I want to move everything to the next step..

Comment: Can you explain why I should use interface over class? I will research online for the difference..  Thanks

Comment: @ChrisFazzio Conceptually, you want to use an interface if you have common behaviour (a plane and a bird can both "fly" and implement the `IFly` interface, but a plane isn't a bird and vice-versa) relationship and class inheritance if you have a "is-a" relationship  and composition if you have a "has-a" relationship. You can look at [this SO for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo).

Comment: Thanks.. I did look it up.. I pretty much get it..  but trying to get the stuff that was given here to work with the stuff I made already seems a little hard..  anyway, I made a public interface IData  with the vars I need.. and now I need to figure out how to set them vars from the variable data types.. I think I am on the right path.